# unable to generate new bundle seed id, is it ok to use the same?

Tags: iphone, ios

i just finished my iPad versions (full and lite) of my game Let's Spot It.they use different bundle seed id. (just like different apps)
then i want to work on its iphone versions. but i am not able to find the option for "generate new" bundle seed id.

```
Bundle Seed ID (App ID Prefix)
Use your Team ID or select an existing Bundle Seed ID for your App ID.
```

what happened? 
I don't use high level techniques like sharing data between 2 of my apps. so can i use the same app id as other apps(which have nothing to do with this app), or can i just use the team bundle seed id? if i use team id, what should i do in my xcode project?

Comment: Just going through the Apple documentation, I noticed that: "you can create a single App ID for your entire application suite utilizing a trailing asterisk as a wild-card character. The wild-card character must be the last character in the App ID string."
Does your App ID string have a trailing asterisk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last time I used my team ID as the bundle seed for a new app ID the website produced a new  bundle seed, different from all previous seeds. I think this is just a confusingly labeled option on the website.

You can reuse one bundle seed for multiple apps, even if those apps do not interact. I have seen suggestions to use only one bundle seed for all your apps, just to give yourself the option to link the programs in future versions. You might want to avoid using the same seed if you are writing apps for multiple third parties, just to keep your customers' products distinct.

Whatever bundle seed you use, just enter the Bundle Identifier into the Info.plist, and add the downloaded provisioning profiles by dragging them onto the Xcode icon.